# label y axis in one week increments ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I would like to produce a graph that labels the y axis every week from April to June using `ggplot2`.

Here is my data:

```
df <- structure(list(year = structure(1:11, .Label = c("2000", "2001", 
"2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", 
"2010"), class = "factor"), greenups_mean = c(107, 106, 124, 
107, 119, 112, 103, 113, 133, 127, 109), greenups.dtime = structure(c(11063, 
11428, 11811, 12159, 12536, 12895, 13251, 13626, 14011, 14371, 
14718), class = "Date"), gmd = c("04-16", "04-16", "05-04", "04-17", 
"04-28", "04-22", "04-13", "04-23", "05-12", "05-07", "04-19"
)), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("year", 
"greenups_mean", "greenups.dtime", "gmd"))
```

I can produce a decent line graph. I use `df$greenups_mean` which is the day of the year, on the y-axis.

```
library (ggplot2)
p <- ggplot (df,aes(x=year,y=greenups_mean)) + geom_line(aes(group=1))
p <- p + ylab('Green-up') + xlab('Year')
p
```

[image]

But, instead of labeling the y-axis with day of year, I would like like to label it weekly from April 1st to June 1st. I assume I would have to pass discrete labels to the plot?

Thanks

-cherrytree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the yaxis in this way, use `scale_y_continuous`

```
p <- ggplot (df,aes(x=year,y=greenups_mean)) + geom_line(aes(group=1))
p <- p + ylab('Green-up') + xlab('Year')
p + scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(91,152,length.out=9),limit=c(90,152),labels=c('Apr 1','Apr 8','Apr 15','Apr 22','Apr 29','May 6', 'May 13', 'May 20','May 27'))
```

[image]

Those exact dates and the ranges for `breaks` might be a little off, but that's the basic idea.

Comment: Actually, I want the weekly tick marks on the y-axis, not the x-axis and for only two months, . Thus, there would only be ~8 tick marks for the 8 wks in April and May.

Comment: Does 'Green-up' refer to day of the year?

Comment: Yes, Green-up refers to day of the year.

Comment: This is perfect @keegan. I wondered if I would have to hard code the y-axis labels. Thanks.